# fsPromises.open() throws an error when opening in append mode

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm trying to open a file to write some data in NodeJS on an Express server using the fs/promises module. I followed the documentation, but when the `open()` method is called, it's throwing an error `ENOENT: no such file or directory`. I verified the file path is correct by opening a terminal in the folder with the script and using `cd [path]` to get to where it's supposed to create the file, and it worked. The path is in a folder that is outside the "server" folder. The folder is in the same level as the "server" folder, so I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

However, per the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system_flags), append mode is *supposed* to create the file if it doesn't exist.

My code:

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
const fsPromises = require('fs/promises');
const moment = require('moment');

router.post('/link',async function(req, res, next) {
    const encryptedData = req.body;
    const fileDate = moment().format("YYYYMMDD_HHms");

    try {
        let filePath = `../../folder/${fileDate}.txt`
        let handle = await fsPromises.open(filePath,'a');
        handle.write(encryptedData).then(writtenObject => {
            if (writtenObject.bytesWritten == 0) {
                console.log("No data was written");
            }
        });
        await handle.close();
        console.log("written");
        res.send(true);
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.send(false);
    };
});
```

What am I missing or doing wrong that it's not creating the file?

Comment: I'm almost sure that the resolved relative path is different from what you think it is. I would recommend adding `console.log(path.resolve(filePath))` before the open command to verify.

Comment: I'll give that a try and update. Thanks!

Comment: That was the issue for sure. It went one level higher than I thought it would. The script is in a sub folder of "server", so I assumed that it would first go up to "server" folder. Is everything in Express executed as running in ```app.js```? That's the only reason I can think of the path going one level higher than intended.

Comment: You'll probably want something like `path.join(__dirname, \`../../folder/${fileDate}.txt\`)`. `__dirname` is the directory containing the .js file you're currently "in". Path operations are always relative to the main script (`app.js` in your case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Christian Fritz and @RickN my path was off. Like mentioned the path is relative to the main script, and after updating the line to

`let handle = await fsPromises.open(path.join(__dirname,filePath),'a');`

it worked.